# How to combine var with var + repeat?

Tags: jquery

I basically need to combine every Name on the textarea with 1234,

That the result would be:

Name:1234

Name:1234

Name:1234

Name:1234

http://jsfiddle.net/ydr52kbx/131/

```
<textarea id="copypass1">1234</textarea>
<textarea id="txtList" rows="5">
Name
Name
Name
Name</textarea>
<input id="copypass2" value="Click" type="button">

$('#copypass2').click(function(){
var list = document.getElementById('txtList').innerHTML;
var copypass = document.getElementById('copypass1').innerHTML;
var copypass = ""+list+":"+copypass+"\n";
var copypass = copypass.repeat(4);
var result = ""+list+":"+copypass+"";
alert (result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text, split it by `\n` and then modify the elements using `Array#map`. Then join the array again by `\n` and set the string to the textarea.

```js
$('#copypass2').click(function() {
  var text = $("#copypass1").val();
  var targetText = $("#txtList").val();
  
  targetText = targetText.split('\n').map(item => {
    if (!item.endsWith(text)) {
      return `${item}: ${text}`;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }).join('\n');
  $("#txtList").val(targetText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="copypass1">1234</textarea>
<textarea id="txtList" rows="10">
Name
Name
Name
Name</textarea>
<input id="copypass2" value="Click" type="button">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#copypass2').click(function(){
       var list = document.getElementById('txtList').innerHTML;
       var copypass = document.getElementById('copypass1').innerHTML;
       list = list.split("\n");
       list.forEach(function(element) {
         alert(element + copypass);
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're using an odd mix of jQuery and native JS methods. If you're taking the penalty of loading jQuery you may as well make use of it's convenience.

To achieve what you require you can use a regular expression to replace the new line character (and the end of the string) with the value from the first `ttextarea`, like this:

```js
$('#copypass2').click(function() {
  var copypass = $('#copypass1').val();
  
  $('#txtList').val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\n|$/g, copypass + '\n');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="copypass1">1234</textarea>
<textarea id="txtList" rows="10">
Name
Name
Name
Name</textarea>
<input id="copypass2" value="Click" type="button">
```